# How to resolve YOLOv4 Error: "Could not locate cudnn_ops_infer64_8.dll please make sure it is in your library path"?

Tags: zlib, darknet, yolov4

Trying to install darknet and use YOLOv4 for detection of objects.

Issue of cudnn_ops_infer64_8.dll unable to locate.

- However the file is in the library.
- I have downloaded Zlib and entered it into the PATH environment.
- Followed the instructions from "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sUxAVpzZ8hU"

What causes the error? And how can i resolve it?

[image: System Information from cmd prompt]

Comment: Do you have installed cudnn 8.4 on your computer?

Answer (score 0):

copy the cudnn .dll file from nvidia folder to your folder containing darknet.exe